# Journey is not recognizing the related object

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect, entry-criteria, salesforce-data-mask

I have a problem on my journey that uses salesforce data as input. It seems that it is not recognizing the criteria of our related object.

At the entrance we are configuring the "rule criterion" step with fields from an object called Course (it is a custom object), and in the settings of the "rule of related objects rule" step we select the fields from the Students object (it is an Account object) that has a relationship with the Courses object.

But, using these criteria the contact simply does not enter the journey.

Then a question arose: as the 1st object that we set up is not of account or contact, can this prevent entry into the journey?

Comment: usually, the most important thing in salesforce data events entry type is the state of the record which needs to transition from false to the true state. Also, are you checking for the creation or the update of the records?

Answer (score 0):

The first step of configuring your Salesforce entry is to select the object. As part of this first step, you are required to select a related Lead/Contact/PersonAccount/User, so if you've come this far, you must have completed this step. I would double check that you've selected the right Lead/Contact/PersonAccount/User to inject into the journey.

Another common 'gotcha' with Salesforce entry events is formula fields. Updates to formula fields won't trigger your journey.